# WIF .NET 4.5 breaks Windows Server AppFabric configuration tool - how to report and how to workaround?

Tags: wif, appfabric

After moving a WCF service to WIF 4.5 , a number of elements have been added to the web.config schema, such as  "serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true""

Now I am unable to manage the configuration of websites from IIS 7.5 because AppFabric is unable to recognise and load the configuration.

How can this be dealt with and how can I submit a bug to MS on this - I can no longer find the customer advisory blog, and I am not sure where to put this on ms connect.

Comment: I am from Microsoft .NET Framework Compatibility Team. Pls file issue report on https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback and send us email at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com with link to the issue. We would look into it as soon as possible. Regards, Varun Gupta (.NET Framework Compatibility)

Comment: OK, I have sent an email with the connect ticket

Comment: Just to update everyone, Sentinel followed up with me. Sentinel confirmed that the app is built with .NET 4.5 . The app builds and works. It is the AppFabric  management IIS tool that no longer works. I am connecting Sentinel with AppFabric folks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's workaround is :
"You can modify %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\ServiceModel_schema.xml to add  under attribute "principalPermissionMode".   "

Note, if you do this, you can't have a backup copy of the file in that folder, you have to put the backup copy elsewhere, otherwise 'something' complains and the schemas cant be loaded at all.